# What is standard coding practice for a non-blocking assignment to a large register array with variable part select in Verilog?

Tags: digital-logic, fpga, verilog, asic

I couldn't find anything in the [Verilog-2001 standard](https://www.eg.bucknell.edu/%7Ecsci320/2016-fall/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/verilog-std-1364-2005.pdf) about this. For example,  the following code works (Xilinx ISE):

```
reg r1;
always @(posedge clk or posedge rst) begin    
    if (rst) begin
        r1 <= 0;
    end else begin
        r1 <= r1;
        if (cond1) begin
            r1 <= 1'b1;
        end 
    end
end
```

In this case, r1 is updated to 1'b1 when `cond1` is nonzero (@ posedge of clk), otherwise it retains its value (as intended). Similarly:

```
1 reg [1023:0] a_reg;
2 always @(posedge trigger or posedge rst) begin    
3     if (rst) begin
4         a_reg <= 0;
5     end else begin
6         a_reg <= a_reg; // required?
7         a_reg[i*2 +: 2] <= input; 
8     end
9 end
```

Is line 6 required? What is considered acceptable practice for FPGA and ASIC design? I would imagine line 6 is not required (as per the definition of a register, it should hold its value between assignments). Or does it depend on the compiler / synthesis tool (DC Compiler, Xilinx ISE/Vivado, Altera Quartus, etc)? Is there something in the standard that sheds light on this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`r1 <= r1` is not required in any synthesiser, as it is in the definition of RTL. Since the logic is written under `@posedge clk`, it is implicit that the previous value of a the register `r1` should be held in that clock cycle if `r1` is not driven any value at that clock edge ie., in this case, if the condition `cond1` is violated.

This is true for the second example as well. The `a_reg` vector is formed by 1024 1-bit registers. Therefore the earlier conclusion we made on 1-bit register `r1`, is applicable to each register in `a_reg` vector as well.

Comment: Would you happen to have a source or material which covers this? Or is this just implied in the Verilog standard?

Comment: This is implied for a sequential logic written in any RTL.